# Bind key prefix + ; to open command-prompt in tmux

Tags: key-bindings, tmux

Normal way to open the command-prompt in `tmux` is `prefix + :`. I want to bind the sequence `prefix + ;` to open the command prompt. I am too lazy to hit the shift key.

When I put this in my `tmux.conf`: `bind-key ; command-prompt`, I get this error: `/Users/skilbjo/.tmux.conf:19: usage: bind-key [-cnr] [-t mode-table] [-T key-table] key command [arguments]`

which is funny, because when I do `prefix + ?` (alias for `tmux list-keys`), this is listed: `bind-key -T prefix : command-prompt`. How does this sorcery work? I even tried `bind-key -T prefix ; command-prompt` to no avail, same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tmux uses semicolon as a command separator, so you'll need to escape it when using it in a bind.

You can unbind the current key used to enter command mode, and set a new one. As below.

From the tmux man page:

> Multiple commands may be specified together as part of a command sequence.  Each command should be separated by spaces and a semicolon; commands are executed sequentially from left to right and lines ending with a backslash continue on to the next line, except when escaped by another backslash.  A literal semicolon may be included by escaping it with a backslash (for example, when specifying a command sequence to bind-key).

What you'll want to do is:

```
unbind-key :
bind-key \; command-prompt
```